# How to use Action Filters with Dependency Injection in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, action-filter

I use constructor-based dependency injection everywhere in my `ASP.NET CORE` application and I also need to resolve dependencies in my action filters:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int Limit { get; set; } // some custom parameters passed from Action
    private ICustomService CustomService { get; } // this must be resolved

    public MyAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // my code
        ...

        await next();
    }
}
```

Then in Controller:

```
[MyAttribute(Limit = 10)]
public IActionResult()
{
    ...
```

If I put ICustomService to the constructor, then I'm unable to compile my project. So, how do I supossed to get interface instances in action filter?

Comment: Can you add setter in the property CustomService so that it is writable also? and add ICustomService as parameter in constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Core (MVC 6) - Inject service into Action Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/asp-net-core-mvc-6-inject-service-into-action-filter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a parameter to an action filter in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to avoid the Service Locator pattern you can use DI by constructor injection with a `TypeFilter`.

In your controller use

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(MyActionFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[] {10})]
public IActionResult() NiceAction
{
   ...
}
```

And your `ActionFilterAttribute` does not need to access a service provider instance anymore.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int Limit { get; set; } // some custom parameters passed from Action
    private ICustomService CustomService { get; } // this must be resolved

    public MyActionFilterAttribute(ICustomService service, int limit)
    {
        CustomService = service;
        Limit = limit;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await next();
    }
}
```

For me the annotation `[TypeFilter(typeof(MyActionFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[] {10})]`seems to be awkward. In order to get a more readable annotation like `[MyActionFilter(Limit = 10)]`your filter has to inherit from `TypeFilterAttribute`. My answer of [How do I add a parameter to an action filter in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net) shows an example for this approach.

Comment: You can also use `IAsyncActionFilter` instead of `IActionFilter` if you need async

Answer (score 36):

You can use `Service Locator`:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
{
     var service = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IService>();
}
```

Note that the generic method `GetService<>` is an extension method and lives in namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

If you want to use constructor injection use `TypeFilter`. See [How do I add a parameter to an action filter in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net)

Comment: It is a good suggestion, however it requires more work to unit test it.

Comment: Works for me - when my class 'ApiKeyAuthAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter' used constructor injection, I could not decorate my controller '[ApiKeyAuth(thingToInject)]' nor could I use '[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiKeyAuthAttribute))]', whereas avoiding constructor injection altogether using the above and grabbing the resolved thingToInject implementation directly from RequestServices works.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **ServiceFilters** to instantiate the ActionFilters you need in the controller.

In the controller:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(TrackingAttribute), Order = 2)]
```

You need to register TrackingAttribute in the dependency container so the ServiceFilter can resolve it.

Read more about this at https://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/

Comment: The official doc for using `ServiceFilter` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#dependency-injection)

Answer (score 1):

I'm browsing around for more information, seems like what we need is here:

```
The following filters support constructor dependencies provided from DI:
 1. ServiceFilterAttribute
 2. TypeFilterAttribute
 3. IFilterFactory implemented on the attribute.
```

Reference: [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score -1):

A good option is doing this **(Tested in .NET Core 3.1)**:

1. Inside a Filter class put this:

   public static class FilterContainer
   {

   ```
        public class GenericFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                string Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
                Console.WriteLine($"[action]: {Action} STARTING");
            }

            public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
            {
                string Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
                Console.WriteLine($"[action]: {Action} FINISHED");
            }

            public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                string Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
                Console.WriteLine($"[action]: {Action} GIVING RESULT");
            }

            public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
            {
                string Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
                ObjectResult ObjectResult = (ObjectResult)filterContext.Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"[action]: {Action} RESULT GIVEN. Value: {ObjectResult.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Inside the Startup.cs/ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) put this:

   services.AddControllers().AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new FilterContainer.GenericFilter()));

**The result is that a request to any kind of action inside your .NET Core app will go in and out through this pipeline without declaring a filter attribute above any action.**

Let me show you an example inside the Output window of Visual Studio:

```
[action]: JSON STARTING
[action]: JSON FINISHED
[action]: JSON GIVING RESULT
[action]: JSON RESULT GIVEN. Value: TestId: 103, FullName:...
```