# Why do ASP.NET filter attributes have logic inside them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The typical pattern I've seen for implementing a custom filter is to derive from e.g. `ActionFilterAttribute`, and override the `OnActionExecutingAsync()` method:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Custom code here...
    }
}
```

The [documentation for Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters#implementing-a-web-api-authentication-filter) (I know, core exists but I haven't moved on yet) recommends you implement it this way:

> In Web API, authentication filters implement the System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter interface. They should also inherit from System.Attribute, in order to be applied as attributes.

However, by inheriting from an attribute, you [lose the ability to perform dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39256341/2363967). It also just feels wrong to be putting logic in an attribute - the name `Attribute` implies that it is just extra information.

You *can* keep the attribute and the filter logic as two separate classes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomActionAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class CustomActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple => false;
    public IDependency Dependency { get; }

    public CustomActionFilter(IDependency dependency)
    {
        Dependency = dependency;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<RequireClaimAttribute>(true).Any())
            return await continuation();

        // Custom code here
    }
}
```

I personally think this is a cleaner solution, and was wondering why Microsoft chose the former way of implementing things. What are the downsides to keeping the attribute and the implementation separate?

Comment: Sounds like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic is a better fit for this question and should be moved there. Here it is more likely to be down-voted or closed.

Comment: Good point. Can I move the question, or do I have to close it and ask separately on softwareengineering? I see the option to close/flag as `belongs on another network`, but it doesn't give me the option to choose softwareengineering

Comment: You are describing passive attributes which Mark Seemann goes into detail [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/)

Comment: @Jasen when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Software Engineering site (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)