# How Do You Add ILogger To GlobalErrorHandling In .net 5 Web Api

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net5

I have my exception hander:

```
    public class ApplicationExceptionHandler :ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public ApplicationExceptionHandler()
        {
        }
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            ApiError apiError = null;
            switch (context.Exception)
            {
                case  TaxiNotFoundException:
                    apiError = new ApiError(context.Exception.Message);
                    context.Result = new ObjectResult(apiError) {StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound };
                    break;
                default:
                    context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
                    break;
            }
            base.OnException(context);
        }
    }

   public class ApiError
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public ApiError(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

    [ApplicationExceptionHandler]
    public class TaxisController : ControllerBase
    { etc....
```

How do I use the ILogger in the exception handler. If I make a constructor:

```
        public ApplicationExceptionHandler(ILogger<ApplicationExceptionHandler> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
```

In my controller I receive an compiler exception:

```
    [ApplicationExceptionHandler (ILogger < ApplicationExceptionHandler > logger)]
```

Logger is a type which is not valid in this context. How do you add a ILogger to an exception handler?

Comment: You can find the answer in this post [POST LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256341/how-to-use-action-filters-with-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the syntax on the controller attribute:

```
    [TypeFilter(typeof(ApplicationExceptionHandler))]
```

And the Exception handler:

```
    public class ApplicationExceptionHandler :ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ApplicationExceptionHandler> logger;

        public ApplicationExceptionHandler(ILogger<ApplicationExceptionHandler> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
```