# ServiceFilter and TypeFilter - what is the difference in injection those filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ServiceFilter we must register in Startup.cs.
TypeFilter is injected by Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ObjectFactory, we don't need to register that filter.

So when we should use ServiceFilter and when TypeFilter ?

Answer (score 31):

According to [Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2](https://github.com/ansbilalgit/Books/blob/master/Pro%20ASP.NET%20Core%20MVC%202.pdf) book (download). Chapter 19: **Filters**, page # 615

> When using the TypeFilter attribute, a new instance of the filter
> class is created for every request. This is the same behavior as
> applying a filter directly as an attribute, except that the TypeFilter
> attribute allows a filter class to declare dependencies that are
> resolved through the service provider. The ServiceFilter attribute
> goes a step further and uses the service provider to create the filter
> object. This allows filter objects to be placed under life-cycle
> management as well.

**THE DIFFERENCE**
Since the `ServiceFilter` uses the `ServiceProvider` to resolve the instance of the filter in question, you have control over the lifecycle of the filter which is registered in the startup class:

```
services.AddSingleton<TimeFilter>();
```

From above line of code, the `TimeFilter` will only be created once for the MVC application lifecycle (not for each http request life cycle or when client asks for it) that will serve for all the http requests which is not possible using `TypeFilter` because there is no way you can instruct MVC framework when to instantiate and dispose the filter used under `TypeFilter`.

If the filter is registered as `Singleton` then only one instance of that filter is created which means less work for CLR which is unlike in case of `TypeFilter` that creates new instance of filter class for each http request.

**THE USAGE**
Say you have a `TypeFilter` applied on two action methods, for each HTTP request, a new instance of that `TypeFilter` will be created, the constructor will be called and dependencies will be injected (you can control the life cycle of dependencies using the `Service Provider`). In contrast, with `ServiceFilter` you decide if its `Singleton` or `Scoped` or `Transient`. If its `Singleton` then only one instance is created for all the requests.

**KEY THING TO REMEMBER**

It’s the filter type’s life cycle that we want to manage by using `ServiceFilter` and `Service Provider`. If the filter has dependencies, we already manage that using `Service Provider` like we normally do.

Comment: So, from what I understand, `ServiceFilter` should be used when we don't need to provide constructor parameters, and `TypeFilter` should be used when we do? That way, if we never need to provide parameters, we'll avoid needlessly creating a new instance of `TypeFilter` for each request?

Comment: TypeFilter has IsReusable parameter which allows to singletonize and reuse the instance of the filter, just like AddSingleton does. What's different is (A) filter objects are created by DI container, or by ObjectFactory, (B) lifetime is managed by DI container, or by [something] driven by IsReusable, (C) you can't pass adhoc creation arguments (unless you play hard with DI config), or you can do it in simple declarative hardcoded way, (D) you have to register filter class in DI, or not. All ORs respectively to SF, or TF .

Answer (score 18):

Ok, so [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection):

> - A `ServiceFilter` retrieves an instance of the filter from DI. Using `ServiceFilter` without registering the filter type results in an exception.
> - `TypeFilterAttribute` is very similar to `ServiceFilterAttribute` (and also implements IFilterFactory), **but its type is not resolved directly from the DI container**. Instead, it instantiates the type by using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ObjectFactory`.
>
> Because of this difference, types that are referenced using the `TypeFilterAttribute` **do not need to be registered with the container first** (but they will still have their dependencies fulfilled by the container).

Comment: I know that - but I still don't see when I should use ServiceFilter and when I should use Typefilter.

Comment: So what is exactly `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ObjectFactory`? How does this work if you don't register it with the container?

Answer (score 17):

Both ServiceFilter and TypeFilter are constructed using dependency injection.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#TypeFilterAttribute) the TypeFilter is instantiated using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ObjectFactory` which ultimately allows you to provide constructor parameters yourself (You can see an **Arguments** parameter in its constructor). It also resolves the ones you don't provide.

So you can do something like this:

```
public class AttachMetadataAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public AttachMetadataAttribute(SomeType someValue, ISomeService service)
        {
        }
}
```

And you can use that like this:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AttachMetadataAttribute),
    IsReusable = true,
    Order = 10,
    Arguments = new object[] { someValue})]
```

So here the the first parameter (someValue) is provided by you and the service gets injected by the container.

Note: Careful about **IsReusable**. If it's set to true the injected service is only created once.

Answer (score -3):

If your filter has dependencies that you need to resolve from the container, then use `TypeFilterAttribute`. It allows you [to perform constructor injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181608/7059613).

Comment: As far as I can tell, they both allow this. The difference is between how the filter itself is instantiated.