# ASP.NET Core 2.1 How to pass variables to TypeFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created this typefilter that is supposed to take 2 variables in order for it to send to a method that is linked to the filter. However, I am unable to attach my 2 variables for it to run.

```
public class RolesFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RolesFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(RolesFilterAttributeImpl))
    {

    }

    private class RolesFilterAttributeImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient;
        private string Role;
        private string SecretKey;
        public RolesFilterAttributeImpl(string Role, string SecretKey, ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient)
        {
            this.validateRoleClient = validateRoleClient;
            this.Role = Role;
            this.SecretKey = SecretKey;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"] != null || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
            {
                TokenViewModel tvm = new TokenViewModel
                {
                    Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"],
                    RefreshToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"]
                };
                ValidateRoleViewModel vrvm = new ValidateRoleViewModel
                {
                    Role = Role,
                    SecretKey = SecretKey,
                    Token = tvm
                };
                validateRoleClient.ValidateRole(vrvm);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I declare the filter and it compiles fine. However, I am not able to pass the required variables which are SecretKey and Role through it. Is my typefilter declared correctly?

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RolesFilterAttribute))]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: How are are you passing the parameters? Query? Header? Form? Get/Post/Delete/Put?

Comment: I want to pass it based on this link that i 
 found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658066/servicefilter-and-typefilter-what-is-the-difference-in-injection-those-filters

Comment: So basically [TypeFilter(typeof(RolesFilterAttribute),{"abc","abc"})]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typefilterattribute)

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AddHeaderAttribute),
    Arguments = new object[] { "Author", "Steve Smith (@ardalis)" })]
public IActionResult Hi(string name)
{
    return Content($"Hi {name}");
}
```