# can i use IAsyncActionFilter/OnActionExecutionAsync to handle the action result

Tags: c#, action-filter, .net-core-3.1

In most of my controllers (API) (.net core 3.1) I call a a function and use the response from that function to then create the appropriate action result.
It looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/read")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReadMessage(Guid id)
    {
        ResponseApiModel r = await _messageData.ReadOneMessage(id);

        if (r.ApiResponse != ApiResponse.AllGood)
        {
            if (r.ApiResponse == ApiResponse.NotFound)
                return NotFound(r);
            else
                return BadRequest(r);
        }
    }
```

The thing is that the if statement is basically repeated in multiple actions all over my controllers. 
I would like to be able to move this code to the Action Filter. But cant figure out how to do it. After all how to i pass the ResponeApiModel to the filter.

I moved all other common code to the filter already, so all authentication checks as well as exception is handled in filters. But this i can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dependency injection.

The solution depends on whether you are using `ServiceFilter` or `TypeFilter`:

**When using `ServiceFilter`**:

1) Register message data as a service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<MessageDataService>();
    ...
}
```

2) Resolve the dependency in constructor of your attribute

```
public class TheFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly MessageDataService _messageData;

    public ThrottleFilter(MessageDataService messageData)
    {
        _messageData = messageData;
    }
    ...
}
```

3) Use ServiceFilter attribute

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(TheFilter))]
```

**When using a TypeFilter**, point 1 is not needed.

Sources:

[Dependency Injection in action filters in ASP.NET Core](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core)

[ServiceFilter and TypeFilter - what is the difference in injection those filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658066/servicefilter-and-typefilter-what-is-the-difference-in-injection-those-filters)

Comment: Perhaps i was not super clear. I don't want to move all the code to the filter. Just the "if" statement. as this is the code that is repeated. The calling of a method on (in this case) message service is not consistent. Each action will be making different calls to different services. They will receive the same type of response model. i want to pass that model to my filter and then depending on the type of result create an appropriate action result. such as Ok or BadRequest