# How do I get a DBContext for my API filter? (To access the DB)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a filter in my API (for Auth), but in order to check the tokens I have to look in my database, which is not hard but when I want to get my DataBaseContext through my ctor I can't use the filter anymore. See here:

> This here is a piece of the filter class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ApiAuth : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly DataBaseContext _db;

    public ApiAuth(DataBaseContext db)
        => _db = db;

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
    }
```

> This is a piece of the User Controller

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiAuth]
public class UserController : Controller
{
}
```

The "[ApiAuth]" now gives me an error that it expects a DataBaseContext, which it cannot give it.

> Error "CS7036: No argument was given that matches the formal parameter "db" of "ApiAuth.ApiAuth(Databasecontext)"."

My problem is, I don't know how else to get my context, you can only get it through the ctor, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to check here.

1. Did you register dbcontext in `ConfigureServices` method of startup class?

like this

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

2. Did you register the filter either globally / or as a service in the IoC container in `ConfigureServices`?

with this settings you should get dbcontext there in your filter.

Otherwise you can use service locator pattern to resolve the dbcontext which does not require constructor injection.

`var context = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<DataBaseContext>();`

also your filter should be applied like this

`[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiAuth))]`

Comment: Yes, maybe I have wrongly explained myself, the database etc. work (and yes I have entered it in the startup class).

My problem is, I normally get this DBContext through the constructor with "DataBaseContext db", but for this filter I must not add any parameters to the constructor, otherwise the tag "[ApiAuth]" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: sorry, my first comment if you saw it was in german

Comment: I understand, what happens if you try to use service locator patterm instaed of direct ctor inject?

Comment: So now if I do "[TypeFilter(typeof(ApiAuth))]" instead of "[ApiAuth]" I can start the API and it is reachable, but I get now on a standard query this respons "Id = 35, Status = Faulted, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}""

Comment: If I look at my "_db" in the debugger, it is not NULL but it is incorrect e.g. in my user table there is this message "Message = "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbConte...".

Comment: Sorry if I'm spamming, but if I do "var _context = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<DataBaseContext>();" I get the correct unit for the database. but isn't there a nicer way?

Comment: So in summary, " [TypeFilter(typeof(ApiAuth))]" works partially, so no error but faulty database context and that with the get service it works. but I find that I'm not the nicest way, right?

Comment: @Schecher_1 - use ServiceFilter instead of TypeFilter, TypeFilter would get a new instance every time filter is requested, I think ServiceFilter should work fine. ServiceFilter uses service provider to create the filter object.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping. I am many steps ahead. 

And yes, "[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiAuth))]" works. I still had strange errors, but they were probably because of "async".
(ps you forgot a bracket at the end).

My question is, if you would like to answer it, what is the difference between "[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiAuth))]" and "[ApiAuth]".

Comment: By the way I did it this way because it was explained in a video, which has also worked so far

Comment: Glad it helped, to know what's diference between service and type filter you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658066/servicefilter-and-typefilter-what-is-the-difference-in-injection-those-filters

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice remaining Sunday <3

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the httpContext in your filter (which is usually possible)
then you can just do something like this

```
        public override void onActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filtercontext) 
    {
var db = filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
```