# Get method parameters inside TypeFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, .net-core

There is an API that should check if a user has permissions to execute action on a specific entity. Every method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("foo/{entityId}/{parameter}")]
[HasValidId] // <-- I would like to add this
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(int entityId, string parameter)
{
    // Instead of this:
    if(!service.LoggedInUserHasAccessToEntity(entityId))
        throw("No accesss to entity");
}
```

As you can see, it accepts "entityId" as an input parameter from the url. Then the `LoggedInUserHasAccessToEntity` check is being performed. In case user doesn't have sufficent permissions, an error is returned.

This approach works fine, but I'd really like to replace it with a `TypeFilterAttribute` or something similar to avoid code duplication. So far I have created an empty `HasValidIdAttribute` class.

Is there a way to access `entityId` inside my type filter attribute?

Note: url parsing won't do, as there may be other parameters involved.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net

Comment: My arguments are Api method arguments, not TypeFilter arguments. This will not work, I can't just put [HasValidId("entityId?")], because I don't know it beforehand.

Comment: Cricket noises...