# How to pass parameters to a generic Action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, action-filter

I'm working on an `Asp.net core 5` project targeted `.Net 5`, I try to create an `Action filter` that will receive a property name, and he will recieve a `TEntity` generic type (represent the table to select from) and catch the submitted `model` and get the property value from it (`model`), this `Action Filter` will look in database if a record already has the same value in the past property inside the table passed in `TEntity`.

**My Action filter:**

```
public class RecordShouldNotExistFilter<TEntity>:IActionFilter where  TEntity : class
{

    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public           string     PropertyToBeChecked { get; set; }

    public RecordShouldNotExistFilter( AppDbContext dbContext )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context )
    {
      // Some logic here that uses the PropertyToBeChecked's value
    }


    }

    public void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext   context )
    {
        
    }

}
```

**The problem:**
When I try to apply the filter on my action I don't know how to pass the `PropertyToBeChecked` value.

I paused here :

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RecordShouldNotExistFilter<PedagogicalSequence>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( PedagogicalSequenceModel model )
{
}
```

**The question :**
How can I pass the `PropertyToBeChecked` value ? or how to achieve my object with another way ? except using `Action` parameters

Comment: would this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the property to be checked in the constructor of your filter, like so:

```cs
public RecordShouldNotExistFilter(AppDbContext dbContext, string propertyToBeChecked)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    PropertyToBeChecked = propertyToBeChecked;
}
```

And then pass that value into the filter attribute:

```cs
[TypeFilter(typeof(RecordShouldNotExistFilter<PedagogicalSequence>), Arguments = new object[] { "PropertyName" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PedagogicalSequenceModel model)
{
}
```

Generic attributes aren't supported so your other option is to make a non-generic attribute following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181608/612510) and get the entity type through a `Type` parameter. You would then use reflection to get the generic implementation:

```cs
public class RecordShouldNotExistFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RecordShouldNotExistFilterAttribute(Type entityType, string propertyToBeChecked) 
        : base(typeof(RecordShouldNotExistFilter<>).MakeGenericType(entityType))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { propertyToBeChecked };
    }
}

public class RecordShouldNotExistFilter<TEntity> : IActionFilter where TEntity : class
{
    readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public string PropertyToBeChecked { get; set; }

    public RecordShouldNotExistFilter(AppDbContext dbContext, string propertyToBeChecked)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        PropertyToBeChecked = propertyToBeChecked;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do this instead:

```cs
[RecordShouldNotExistFilter(typeof(PedagogicalSequenceModel), "PropertyName")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PedagogicalSequenceModel model)
```