# How to set properties of the action controller attributes when using TypeFilter initiator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I implemented this attribute in c#:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute,IAsyncAuthorizationFilter {

  private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

  public bool NeedValidat {get; set; }  = true;

  public SnappFoodAuthenticationAttribute(IAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }
  
  public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
    var token = context.HttpContext.Request
                    .Headers ["Authorization"]
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    if (NeedValidate) {
      var extractedTokenData =
          await _authenticationService.ValidateToken(token);
      if (!extractedTokenData.Active) {
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(new Response(
            "AuthenticationError", "Authorization failed. ",
            new List<string>{extractedTokenData.Mesage})){StatusCode = 401};
      }

      context.HttpContext.Items[_authenticationService.GetCurrentUserKey] =
          extractedTokenData;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add this attribute inside my controller, I should use the below syntax due to the Dependency injection Of `_authenticationService`:

```
[HttpPost("action")]
[TypeFilter(typeof(MyAttribute))]
public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResponse>> MyAction([FromBody]SomeActionRequest request)
{

    var result = await myServie.someFunction(request.VendorId);
    return Ok(new SomeResponse( result.Adapt<SomeResponse>()));

}
```

So I need to set the `NeedValidate` based on the called action. Is there any way that I can pass the properties from the attribute?

Comment: I found the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181390/how-do-i-add-a-parameter-to-an-action-filter-in-asp-net