# Using ILogger in ExceptionFilter

Tags: .net, logging, filter, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to use the .NET Core Logger in an ExceptionFilter like this:

```
public class GlobalExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<Inspection> _logger;
    public GlobalExceptionAttribute(ILogger<Inspection> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error");
    }
  ... 
}
```

But in my Controller this leads to an error message, that tells me I need to provide a logger as a parameter:

```
[GlobalException]
public class Inspection : Controller
{
 ...
```

I actually want the logger to be injected automatically by .NET Cores DI. How can I archive that?

Comment: could you post the specific error message

Comment: You need to use ServiceFilter attribute. Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Core (MVC 6) - Inject service into Action Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/asp-net-core-mvc-6-inject-service-into-action-filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not add the logging inside the exception filter attribute. I would let the exception handler do the logging. With that, I will still have a central place for the logging and any exception filters will throw exceptions. In a nutshell, I will achieve making my exception filters lightweight and separated the logging responsibilities. I don't have a code yet ready but will try to post something later.

Answer (score 0):

To use the ILogger in any ExceptioFilter you can receive the ILogger as constructor dependency injection like you did in your answer.

```
public class GlobalExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<Inspection> _logger;
    public GlobalExceptionAttribute(ILogger<Inspection> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error");
    }
  ... 
}
```

But to use the attribute you must call from the ServiceFilter like:

```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(GlobalExceptionAttribute))]
```

Also, register the service adding GlobalExceptionAttribute as Scoped on the startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<GlobalExceptionAttribute>();
```