# Injecting repository in custom filter.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have app written in asp.net core MVC c#

I have written a custom filter as:

```
public class CustomFilter: IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
       //need to call my sqlrepository here 
    }
}
```

How can I call my SQL repository inside my custom filter?

I have my controller as:

```
public class HomeController
{
   private IMySqlRepository _repo; 

  public HomeController(IMySqlRepository myRepo)
    {           
        _repo= myRepo;           
    }
}
```

In my home controller, I can call this fine by above code.

Also just FYI I register this repo in my startup as:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
   services.AddScoped<IMySqlRepository , MySqlRepository >();
 }
```

Comment: How are you applying the filter?

Comment: [Register your filter with DI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36109052/2030565).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject service into Action Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/inject-service-into-action-filter)