# Inject service into Action Filter with Autofac KeyFilterAttibute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I register `ActionFilterAttribute` in `ConfigureServices`, but I want to inject the service in `CustomActionFilter` by `KeyFilter` attribute

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomActionFilter([KeyFilter("test2")]IService service)
    {
    }
}
```

Filter Registration:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<CustomActionFilter>();
}

public class Service1 : IService
{

}

public class Service2 : IService
{

}

builder.RegisterType<Service1>().Keyed<IService>("test1");
builder.RegisterType<Service2>().Keyed<IService>("test2");
```

Is anyone has idea, how can I register filter to support key filtering?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/inject-service-into-action-filter

Comment: You need to make sure that `IService` and any other dependencies of the action filter are registered as well.

Comment: Updated question to make clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `IService` and any other dependencies of the action filter are registered as well.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...

    // Autofac
    services.AddAutofac();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //core integration
    builder.Populate(services);

    // Register the components getting filtered with keys
    builder.RegisterType<Service1>().Keyed<IService>("test1");
    builder.RegisterType<Service2>().Keyed<IService>("test2");

    // Attach the filtering behavior to the component with the constructor
    builder.RegisterType<CustomActionFilter>().WithAttributeFiltering();

    var container = builder.Build();    
    var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);

    return serviceProvider;
}
```

Custom filters are added to the controller method and the controller class using the `ServiceFilter` attribute like so:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomActionFilter))]
[Route("api/custom")]
public class CustomController : Controller {
    // GET: api/issues
    [HttpGet]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomActionFilter))]
    public IActionResult Get() { 
        //...
    }
}
```

Or you could have registered it globally in `ConfigureServices` like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc(options => {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomActionFilter)); // by type        
    });

    //...
}
```

Reference [Filters : Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection)

Reference [AutoFac : KeyFilterAttribute Class](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/9305214F.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what Im looking for. As you see in my sample code, I want to filter IService by key. I have 2 implementation of IService and want to filter them by key

Comment: you mean by default support KeyFilter?

Comment: @Peyman look at the comments in the code. Came from documentation which was also linked at the end of the post.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, just missed first line services.AddAutofac();