# How do you setup unit testable model validation with dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 2 MVC?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application. A lot of the time I need to make use of dependencies to validate user input. I want my validation methods to be unit testable, and I want to be able to inject mocked dependencies into them. This is something I have previously done in MVC5 to great success but cannot work out the ASP.NET Core 2 equivalent.

This is how I would do it in MVC5:

```
// the view model to be validated
public class MyViewModel {
  public string Username { get; set; }
}

// the model validator that will have dependencies injected into it
public class MyViewModelValidator : ModelValidator
{
  private IUserService users;
  private MyViewModel model;

  public MyViewModelValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext, IUserService users)
    : base(metadata, controllerContext)
    {
      this.users = users;
      this.model = base.Metadata.Model as MyViewModel;
    }

  public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
  {
      List<ModelValidationResult> errors = new List<ModelValidationResult>();

      if (this.users.CheckExists(this.model.Username))
      {
          errors.Add(new ModelValidationResult() { MemberName = nameof(MyViewModel.Username), Message = "Username is not available" });
      }

      return errors;
  }
}

// this class works out which validator is required for a given model and 
// injects the appropriate dependencies that is resolves using unity in my
// in my case
public class ViewModelValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
  private IUnityContainer container;

  public ViewModelValidatorProvider() => this.container = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnityContainer>();

  public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
  {
    if (metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyViewModel))
      yield return new MyViewModelValidator(metadata, context, this.container.Resolve<IUserService>());
  }
}

// the provider is hooked up in the app start in Global.asax.cs file
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ViewModelValidatorProvider());
  }
}
```

Now I can just create an instance of the validator with mocked dependencies and away I go! Sadly ASP.NET Core 2 doesn't have the `ModelValidator` class and everything I have found so far seems to want to inject dependencies via the controller or to resolve them with in an `IValidatableObject`s `Validate()` function.

Is it possible to do this in MVC Core?

Comment: See if this may be of some use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/inject-service-into-action-filter/36109690#36109690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following the post @Nkosi left in a comment on the question I started down the right path (I think) and ended up implementing a validation system based on [type filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection).

To start I have a base validator model that we need to implement in our type filters:

```
    public abstract class BaseViewModelValidator<TModel> : IAsyncActionFilter
    where TModel : class
{
    public async virtual Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // get the model to validate
        if (context.ActionArguments["model"] is TModel model)
            await this.ValidateAsync(model, context.ModelState);
        else
            throw new Exception($"View model of type `{context.ActionArguments["model"].GetType()}` found, type of `{typeof(TModel)}` is required.");

        await next();
    }

    public abstract Task ValidateAsync(TModel model, ModelStateDictionary state);        
}
```

Then, because it is much nicer to use it as a named attribute rather than `[TypeFilter(typeof(SomeActionFilter))]`, I create a `TypeFilterAttribute` that wraps the implementation of my base validator like this:

```
public class DemoViewModelValidatorAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public DemoViewModelValidatorAttribute() 
        : base(typeof(DemoViewModelValidator))
    {
    }

    internal class DemoViewModelValidator : BaseViewModelValidator<DemoViewModel>
    {
        private readonly ISomeService service;

        // dependencies are injected here (assuming you've registered them in the start up)
        public DemoViewModelValidator(ISomeService service) => this.service = service;

        public async override Task ValidateAsync(DemoViewModel model, ModelStateDictionary state)
        {
            if (await this.service.CheckSomethingAsync(model))
                state.AddModelError(nameof(model.SomeProperty), $"Whoops!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then unit test your `DemoViewModelValidator` to your hearts content! Hopefully someone finds this useful!