# How to the pass the URL from action filter to main controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my action filter, I am getting the user visited URL through this code.

MyActionFilter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        String originalPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;

    }
}
```

I need to pass the originalPath to the main controller in order to save the URL into db. How do I pass the url from action filter to main controller?

Main controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly MyLogEntities _db = new MyLogEntities();
   [LogActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [LogActionFilter]
    public ActionResult About(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        var usr = _db.UserLogs.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
        var inputUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["INPUT_USER"].ToString().ToLower();
        usr.Date = DateTime.Now;
        usr.url= originalPath; // need to get this from action filter
        usr.UserName = inputUser;
        _db.Logs.Add(usr);
        _db.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Added;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement the whole logging inside the action filter. It would make your code cleaner. Anyway, you could use `ActionExecutingContext.ActionParameters` to pass data or why don't you simply get it where you need it, without the action filer at all? The controller has the same context while the action is called.

Comment: The easy answer is to throw it into `ViewBag` or `HttpContext.Item[]`. The slightly harder answer is to log it directly from the filter, although to be elegant you should inject the service ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/inject-service-into-action-filter/36109690)).

Comment: @ZorgoZ sounds good. I never thought of this one. how can I implement the whole logging inside the action filter?