# IHttpClientFactory using in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-core

I facing a big problem when using HttpClientFactory in ActionFilterAttribute.  From Microsoft docuemnt [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)  I need to register it in Startup.ConfigureServices method.  When I use the HttpClientFactory that I just need to declare it in Controller

```
public TestController(IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
```

That fine, it is OK for me.  But if I need to use it in ActionFilterAttribute.  How can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109052/inject-service-into-action-filter/36109690

Comment: Thank you your answer.  It seem it resolved my problem but I think it is very complicated for me.  I resolved my problem that just cast (TestController) context.Controller in ActionFilterAttribute that I can get HttpClientFactory now.  Anyway I will make your answer.